# Action you have requested is not allowed error

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

I made a module named Gallery which works fine on my localhost with version 2.0.3, but when using version 2.1.0 on a remote site I can not submit a form and I get the error:

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

Why is this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a Codeigniter error related to the CSRF protection. You can cancel it in `cms/config/config.php`

Comment: Of course, turning off the CSRF protection means you are left open to CSRF attacks.

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot with a problem trying to upload files using AJAX requests, with Plupload and Codeigniter.

Comment: I agree with HighlyIrregular this doesn't really solve the problem, it works around it and leaves OP open to CSRF attacks. JoeMoe1984 and Jhourlad Estrella have the better answers. We shouldn't be encouraging less-secure coding/development practices.

Comment: It is obvious security is must so that disable CSRF is not recommended. When we enable the CSRF in CI, in every forms it it adds something like this `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="4ac7a11a8239660afaa87cb48f2694e2" style="display:none;" />` but the above error occurs when we use `<form> .... </form>` it because CI don't add  that hidden input when we use `<form> .... </form>` and when we submit form without the CSRF token while CSRF enabled it give the above error. All you have to do is use `<?php echo form_open();?>` and `<?php echo form_close();?>`

Answer (score 25):

I agree with @Jhourlad Estrella on fixing the problems instead of disabling a security feature, however I feel that the real problem is with the hidden input field that holds the token.

Instead of using plain HTML to create a form element use the the `form_open()` and `form_close()` helper functions. The reason why is because when you use the helper function it automatically inserts the csrf token as a hidden field in the form.

You could do this manually as well by adding the token as a hidden input field in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_hash_name" value="your-hash-value-here">
```

Doing it this way will allow you to stay protected from CSRF attacks and fix the problem you are having.

Hope this helps someone else out there as this was driving me nuts the first time figuring this out.

Comment: @AaronBruce Yeah I unfortunately answered this a year late lol. Hopefully it will get noticed enough though.

Comment: If you can't use `form_open()` or `form_close()` you can get the CSRF token name and value using `$this->security->get_csrf_hash();` and `$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();`

Answer (score 3):

On matters of programming, you don't go around problems, you fix it. What I mean to say is, this feature won't be here if it is unusable: 'coz it is and it works for me. You just have a problem on the implementation.

My answer: Remove all dashes, periods and any other non-alphanumeric characters from the values of following entries on application/config/config.php as seen below:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'mycookiename'; //instead of "my_cookie_name"
$config['csrf_token_name']  = 'mycsrftoken';  //instead of "my.csrf.token"
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'mycsrfcookie'; //instead of "my/csrf/cookie"
```

BTW, dashes sometimes work but I suggest using single words whenever possible when naming config values. Not unless you have the time and skills to study Codeigniter's core files related to what ever you are working on just to make sure it's safe to do so.

Anyways, I hope this help somebody out there even though my answer is more than a year late.

Answer (score 3):

I have a form that was built outside of CI (in Joomla), but that I wanted to process with CI. My fix was to selectively disable csrf for specific referrers. I added this to config, directly after the default config options for csrf:

```
/* Set csrf off for specific referrers */
$csrf_off = array(
    "http://yourdomain.com/your-form-url",
    "http://yourdomain.com/some-other-url"
);

if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
    if (in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],$csrf_off)) {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = false;
    }
}
```

This disables csrf protection for specific URLs in the $csrf_off array, but leaves it intact for all other requests.

Comment: I know it's old, but this approach does help me solve the issue of using CKEDITOR while csrf is on. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have found using the form helper functions

Example

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/function');?>

<?php echo form_input('username', 'Username');?>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Using the helper functions like above should stop the CSRF error message showing.

If I don't use echo form_input() if I place just normal input will trigger the CSRF error when reload.

```
<?php echo form_open('controller/function');?>

<input type="text" name="username" />

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

So I recommend using all form helper functions now.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but this same problem did cost me so much time that I wanted to share what the problem was in my case. It may help someone.

I am using Codeigniter 3.0.6 and CommunityAuth 3 together with it and I was getting this error after a login.

It was confusing since the problem would sometimes happen and would not other times.

My 'base_url' in CI's config.php was set to something like 'www.mysite.com'

When you browse the site with 'mysite.com' (notice 'www' is not in the address) and you do a form submission that uses CI's 'base_url' setting, like CommunityAuth's login does, then CSRF check fails and you get 'The action you have requested is not allowed.' error.

Comment: I think a good solution to this problem is to pick a 'preferred' address - either with 'www' or without - and redirect all traffic to that preferred address with htaccess. In addition to solving this problem, it will prevent search engines from indexing www and non-www content separately, which can hurt search engine rankings. My rewrite looks as follows:  
`## REWRITE www traffic to root domain`    
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]`    
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=302,L]`  
(FYI - I can't seem to get line breaks to work here - sorry so sloppy)

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown by the function csrf_show_error() in `system/core/Security.php` when the CSRF token in $_COOKIE doesn't match your $_POST['csrf_token_name'].

Inside `config.php`, I had to ensure that `$config['cookie_domain']` matched `$config['base_url']`, without the protocol (i.e. `http(s)://`).

Otherwise, the cookie wasn't being passed which meant the match couldn't be made.

Answer (score 0):

Use the codeigniter form opener like this:

```
<php echo form_open(url,method,attributes);?>
```

see codeigniter form documentation for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a rare case, but I didn't see my issue since my server has many different domain names that are very similar.  The problem was that I was landing on a domain that was completely wrong, but since "The action you have requested is not allowed." error takes precedence over " 404 Not Found Error" I couldn't see it.  My problem was that I didn't change my base_url to the correct domain.  So if none of the above solutions work for you, you might check your settings for $config['base_url'] in application/config.

Answer (score 0):

Im Using Codeigniter 3 same problem with

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

Based on Isaac Pak's point, i changed my base_url to what i usally typed at the address bar. like this...

instead of putting

> `http://www.domain.org`

i write it this way..

> `http://domain.org`

since my `base_url()` is just..

> `$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain.org/';`

the fix works for my site...

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I was loading the view in the index, than I changed as follow and it worked:

```
public function index()
{
    // Load Login Page
    redirect('login/login_page','refresh');

}

public function login_page()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Login Page';

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('users/login_view', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```